# I want to read text from Google OCR API and store in database

Tags: android, database, ocr

I have developed an App using Google OCR API which can read text from scanned images.I want to store the text in the database. i want the complete code to read text from image and store it in the database.

Comment: Have you tried anything to store the values so far? Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score -1):

Following Code helps to extract the text from the image

```
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'

    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

Frame imageFrame = new Frame.Builder()

        .setBitmap(bitmap)                
        .build();

String imageText = "";


SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = textRecognizer.detect(imageFrame);

for (int i = 0; i < textBlocks.size(); i++) {
    TextBlock textBlock = textBlocks.get(textBlocks.keyAt(i));
    imageText = textBlock.getValue();                   

}`
```

$imageText returns the text which you can dump to your database

Comment: Hi Thanks.I am quite new in android... i need the entire code/project ..which will read text from image and store in database simultaneously.